# How to get the values of pull request Created by and Approved by in Azure DevOps CI pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the pull-request build in Azure DevOps in that I have used inline PowerShell script to get the **Pull Request ID** by following [System variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) documentation.

But I want to get the values of Pull Request **Created by** and **Approved by** using predefined variables.

So, can anyone suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no predefined variables of Created by or Approved by for a Pull Request. Instead, you could use [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to get these information, as you have had Pull Request ID:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=6.0
```

In the response, you could get `createdBy` value:

[image]

Regarding Approved by value, you could get `vote` in `reviewers`. The vote with value 10 are the approvers.

```
Vote on a pull request:
10 - approved 5 - approved with suggestions 0 - no vote -5 - waiting for author -10 - rejected
```

[image]

You could use the powershell to run the api:

```
Param(
   [string]$org = "orgname",
   [string]$projectName = "projectname",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = " ",
   [string]$token = "YourPAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$projectName/_apis/git/pullrequests/$pullrequestid?api-version=6.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host "$($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Comment: Dong, can you please update your answer with to integrate the above logic into CI pipeline.

Comment: You could use REAT API in the powershell script directly, do you mean you don't know how to use REAT API in the powershell script?

Comment: I've added a script how to use the api, you could check it.